# How to limit the data getting from database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I want to limit the data it's getting from the mysql database, Here's my code,

```
<div id="accordion" class="col-lg-8 faq">
                @foreach($faq as $vfaq)
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{$vfaq->id}}">
                        <span><button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$vfaq->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{$vfaq->id}}">{{$vfaq->question}}</button></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse{{$vfaq->id}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{$vfaq->id}}" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>{!! $vfaq->answer!!}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
</div>
```

How can I do this? I'm using laravel for this application

Comment: What type of limitation you want can you explain it?

Comment: Can you please show the code for getting the `$faq`s? Maybe you should already limit your results when querying the database and not only in the view.

Comment: You are showing the front end which is responsible for showing the data. You need to show us the backend which is responsible for retrieving the data. You could use take(10)->get() on the backend.

Comment: @IrshadKhan i want to limit the faqs which shown in the frontend

Comment: @codedge There's 2 pages. One is home page and other one is faq page. I only want to show 5 in home page but it should show all in the faq page

Comment: @Savlon this is backend - public function faq()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Faq";
        return view('front.faq', $data);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AppServiceProvider.php,

You can add this code  `$data['faq2']=DB::table('faq')->take(5)->get();` to limit the records differently. And then Add this code to where you want to show the limited records.

```
@foreach($faq2 as $vfaq)
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{$vfaq->id}}">
                        <span><button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$vfaq->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{$vfaq->id}}">{{$vfaq->question}}</button></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse{{$vfaq->id}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{$vfaq->id}}" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>{!! $vfaq->answer!!}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

Thanks for helping everyone

Answer (score 1):

what condition you want? you can specify data using where clause. limit means if **$faq** return 10 row, you can limit that using sql limit. or read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset

Comment: There's 2 pages. One is home page and other one is faq page. I only want to show 5 in home page but it should show all in the faq page